# Flutter : Draggable rows in SfDataGrid

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I want to reorder the table rows manually by drag and droping. I created a table using SfDataGrid. And how can I implement this reordering now?

Code:

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datagrid/datagrid.dart';

class RegReqTable extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegReqTable({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<RegReqTable> createState() => _RegReqTableState();
}

class _RegReqTableState extends State<RegReqTable> {
  List<Employee> employees = <Employee>[];
  late EmployeeDataSource employeeDataSource;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    employees = getEmployeeData();
    employeeDataSource = EmployeeDataSource(employeeData: employees);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          Text('Requests',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          Expanded(
            child: SfDataGrid(
              source: employeeDataSource,
              columnWidthMode: ColumnWidthMode.fill,
              columns: <GridColumn>[
                GridColumn(
                    columnName: 'user',
                    label: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text(
                          'User',
                        ))),
                GridColumn(
                    columnName: 'request',
                    label: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text(
                          'Request details',
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ))),
                GridColumn(
                    columnName: 'accept',
                    label: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text(
                          'Accept',
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ))),
               
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Employee> getEmployeeData() {
    return [
      Employee('User 1','Blah blah blah'),
      Employee('User 1','Blah blah blah'),
      Employee('User 1','Blah blah blah'),
    ];
  }
}

class Employee {
  late String user;
  final String request;

  Employee( this.user, this.request);

}

/// An object to set the employee collection data source to the datagrid. This
/// is used to map the employee data to the datagrid widget.
class EmployeeDataSource extends DataGridSource {
  /// Creates the employee data source class with required details.
  EmployeeDataSource({required List<Employee> employeeData}) {
    _employeeData = employeeData
        .map<DataGridRow>((e) =>
        DataGridRow(cells: [
          DataGridCell<String>(columnName: 'user', value: e.user),
          DataGridCell<String>(
              columnName: 'request', value: e.request),
          const DataGridCell<Widget>(columnName: 'accept', value: null),
  
        ]))
        .toList();
  }

  List<DataGridRow> _employeeData = [];

  @override
  List<DataGridRow> get rows => _employeeData;
  @override
  DataGridRowAdapter buildRow(DataGridRow row) {
    return DataGridRowAdapter(
        cells: row.getCells().map<Widget>((e) {
          return Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: e.columnName == 'accept'
                  ? LayoutBuilder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                    return ElevatedButton(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                              Colors.green),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Text('Accept'));
                  })
                  : Text(e.value.toString()));
        }).toList()
    );
  }
}
```

The above code is the table I created. I wanna make it as reorderable manually based on drag and drop. Can Someone give me a solution for this code? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score -1):

I think the reorderable package can help you with that task [Reorderables2](https://pub.dev/packages/reorderables2)